# entity type has no key defined - Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I'm new to MVC as well as the entity framework. I searched lot and find few similar questions (e.g. [Entity Type Has No Key Defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290511/entity-type-has-no-key-defined)) but they don't solve my problem.

```
namespace MvcAppInvoice.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SurName { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomerType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerType
    {
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Customer> customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: Add Controller]

When I try to add the controller it gives the following error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typically, code first by convention implicitely sets key for entity type if property is named `Id` or `TypeName+Id`. In your case, `TypeId` is neither of them, so you should explicitely mark it as key, using [KeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute.aspx) or with fluent syntax, using [EntityTypeConfiguration.HasKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671266%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: I modified as you suggest, but even it gives same error: please see the edit in question

Comment: That should have fixed error. Maybe you should rebuild solution to make it work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I restarted the project 3 times before I found the solution that worked for me.  I had a public class that I manually created called UserContext.  When I ran the wizard to add an ADO class the wizard generated a partial class of UserContext.  I deleted my usercontext class and I modified the class that VS generated for me.

```
namespace UserLayer.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public class UserContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now it may have had worked without the modification.  Perhaps deleting my version of the class would have work.  I do not know. In retropect I encountered your error when I tried to add the controller.  I suspect this is a bug in VS2012 because a partial class and a public class of the same name can exist.  The intent is to allow the programmer to extend the definition of the partial class.

Answer (score 1):

Add namespace

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Add key attribute to your CustomerID
like this

```
[Key]
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
```

then build the application and try to add controller. This will work

Answer (score 0):

there was an error running the selected code generator unable to retrieve metadata for entity type has no key defined.

- one more important thing sql table only takes [Id] then entity
  framework will work if you use other primary key like[MenuId] it
  wont.
- you should add validation on Model which is Key and Column order
- column order = 1 because after [key] added its increment by 1 that's
  why

Model

```
[Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int RoleIdName { get; set; }
```

then build this after create a controller under entity frame work it will work

i hope it helps.