# Entity type has no key defined EF6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, models

Here is my code although I already have refined the key attribute but still there is a problem.

```
public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The error I get is:

> Entity Type 'Contacts'  has no key defined. Define the key for this entity type. 
>   Entity type: EntitySet 'Contacts' is based on type 'Contacts' that has no key defined

Comment: Really? Did you rebuild after setting the `Key` attribute? Besides, I'd rather call the class `Contact`, because it represents 1 contact, not a collection of contacts.

Comment: yes @Gert i did rebuild it,but the problem as in naming convention of class and ID. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Well, good for you, but it doesn't make sense. The key attribute should be enough here. I think something else is going on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207967/entity-type-has-no-key-defined-code-first/45372519#45372519 check this out. this is your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using EF Code First (not specified in your question), you will need to change the ContactId property name to ContactsId to match the convention of *ClassName* + Id in order to define the key for your *Contacts* entity type.

See the MSDN Code First Conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Comment: When there is a `Key` attribute the conventions don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has already been answered in one fashion, but I wanted to post a different approach for those who encounter this.

This error occurred for me even while having [Key] defined above the property I wanted to designate as the Primary Key. The error, occurring during the Update-Database command, was caused by my naming of the migration (through Add-Migration) the same as the entity that I wanted to be added. This is because the Add-Migration command created a partial class which matched the entity name.

For example:

```
public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Didn't work when I executed:

```
Add-Migration Contacts
Update-Database
```

because the migration class signature looked like the below, and the body contained no property with the [Key] attribute

```
public sealed partial class Contacts
```

To solve this, I deleted the identically-named migration and modified the Add-Migration command:

```
Add-Migration ContactsTable
Update-Database
```